# Trouble Creating a View for Category Hierarchy

Tags: javascript, arrays, hierarchy

I have created `category hierarchy` following a tutorial here : [Model Tree Structures with An Array of Ancestors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/) . When I do query, I am getting result which is identical to the following array dump.

```
[
    {id:1,name:'A', ancestors:[]}

        ,{id:2,name:'AA',parent:1, ancestors:[1]}

            ,{id:4,name:'AAA',parent:2, ancestors:[1,2]}
            ,{id:5,name:'AAB',parent:2, ancestors:[1,2]}

        ,{id:3,name:'AB',parent:1, ancestors:[1]}

            ,{id:6,name:'ABA',parent:3, ancestors:[1,3]}
            ,{id:7,name:'ABB',parent:3, ancestors:[1,3]}

    ,{id:8,name:'B', ancestors:[]}
]
```

Can anybody help me on yielding the following output to be used in a view from the above data:

```
ul
    li A
        ul
            li AA
                ul
                    li AAA
                    li AAB
            li AB
                ul
                    li ABA
                    li ABB
    li B
```